# Google Forms/Sheets - How to recover ownership access for a form and sheet that has no Owners, only Editors?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-forms

I have inherited a Google Form with its corresponding Sheet, for which the original owner is unknown. In the list of collaborators, there is no owner. Everyone at the company who has access is only an Editor, including me.

There are two problems:

1. I need to have ownership of the form and sheet.
2. I need to remove some of the Editors who no longer work for us and should not have access.

The accompanying Google Sheet has the same problem. I don't know what to do here. This seems like a strange oversight by Google to allow this situation to occur.

[image]

Comment: "In the list of collaborators, there is no owner"
The owner is always there, but for some reason he is not displayed in the list.
Have you tried to find out the owner using a script?

Comment: Try this code:
`function getOwner() {
   // TODO: Replace the file name with your own.
   const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('FILENAME');
   while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    console.log(file.getOwner().getEmail());
    console.log(file.getOwner().getName());
   }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If your files were created with a consumer account, whether the primary email address is gmail.com or another domain, only the owner can transfer ownership to another user. If this is the case with this pair of Google Form and Google Sheets files, the only option to have owner rights is to create a new pair of files by making a copy or starting from scratch.

If the files were created using a Google Workspace account, ask an administrator to transfer the file's ownership to another account.